# What is the purpose of "t" in the moment generating function?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and its mgf $m(t)=e^{{t^2}/2}$. The third moment of Z is the third derivative of the mgf: $m^3(t)=t^3 e^{{t^2}/2}+2te^{{t^2}/2}...$ at $t=0$.

Why is $t$ set to zero? Is it question specific? I never really understood what the $t$ was, I just thought each distribution came with a specific value of $t$ that would make the mgf "work" for it...

Comment: So, the moments are encode in the coefficients of the expansion of the generating function around $0$. So if you differentiate $n$ times and you plug $0$ you recover the coefficient(so the moment)

Comment: So you mean whenever the question asks me to find a k-th moment, essentially I always plug in zero?

Comment: Yes. You differentiate $k$ times and plug in $0.$ Make and experiment. Take an exponential series. Differentiate say, $4$ times, what do you get?

Comment: Mmm I see. Taking the third derivative since I'm lazy it's $m^3 (x)=\frac{1}{36} + \frac{1}{288}x^2...$ and by setting all the x's to zero you just get 36? I guess this is beyond the scope of discussion for now but is there a reason WHY we do this? E.g. why don't we set t=1 and sum to infinity? Is there a reading I can look at?

Comment: A generating function is just a way of encoding a sequence.  I have an answer on here about generating functions that I think is appropriate.

Comment: The post is under the question. What is a generating function in combinatorics?  Not sure how to link from my phone. I'd merely add the moments are the sequence you wish to encode.

Comment: @Phicar do you want to post your answer as an answer so I can vote? Yours was the one that helped the most

Comment: @Five9 You should accept J.G's. Is what i said and better explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two questions here, each warranting a paragraph.

The mgf $m(t)$ is a function of a dummy parameter $t$, just as the CDF $F(x)$ is a function of a dummy parameter $x$. They're two different ways to describe the distribution's degrees of freedom with a function.

Since $m(t)=\Bbb E\exp tX$, the $n$th derivative $m^{(n)}(t)=\Bbb EX^n\exp tX$, so $m^{(n)}(0)=\Bbb EX^n$. This use of $t=0$ is applicable to any distribution for which the MGF is differentiable $n$ times at $0$.